# Meaning of following statement:

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I came across this statement and I can't understand the overall concept of the part I have made bold:

> "Current trends in scholarship demonstrate a new historical and ethnographic consciousness. Since the late 1970s scholarship has increased exponentially, with perhaps half a dozen books now being published annually in English. Highly focused analyses continue, now bringing new analytical tools to the table, including native fluency in language. **Single book-length surveys of the continent have not been taken up in force, perhaps in recognition of the enormity of the task.**"

Google Books: ['The Harvard Dictionary of Music' By Don Michael Randel](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=02rFSecPhEsC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=Single%20book-length%20surveys%20of%20the%20continent%20have%20not%20been%20taken%20up%20in%20force,%20perhaps%20in%20recognition%20of%20the%20enormity%20of%20the%20task&source=bl&ots=Ul8YOKRmUL&sig=q5i4AOGiQqakcKjUu30E-iK3jfY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQg5mZi_vMAhWGM48KHWPIDbkQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=Single%20book-length%20surveys%20of%20the%20continent%20have%20not%20been%20taken%20up%20in%20force%2C%20perhaps%20in%20recognition%20of%20the%20enormity%20of%20the%20task&f=false)

Comment: Which specific aspect of the text is giving you problems? Are you familiar with the construction [Demonstrators were out in force](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/in--force), for example?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source? It's often difficult to understand a sentence out of context.

Comment: that's whole paragraph: "historical and ethnographic consciousness. Since the late  1970s scholarship has increased exponentially, with perhaps half a dozen books now being published annually in English. Highly focused analyses continue, now bringing new analytical tools to the table, including native fluency in language. Single book-length surveys of the continent have not been taken up in force, perhaps in recognition of the enormity of the task."

Comment: I think that 'Single' refers to 'surveys', not 'book'. So, there are not a lot of books that survey the music of the whole of Africa, as this is a big task to fulfill.

Comment: @Keepthesemind I think you're on the right track. You should post an answer. :)

Comment: Hello @user3705340, You can select an entire phrase and search on google to find its source. And I have done it for you this time.

Comment: @user3705340 I've only improved the formatting. You'll need to improve the question by telling us which part of the bold phrase you find confusing.

Comment: For other readers it should be noted that the context of the quote is African music, so "continent" refers to the continent of Africa.

Comment: They're probably just misusing "enormity" here to mean "enormous size"; that is, he's just saying that no one has taken on the task of a book-length survey of the continent because they know it's a huge job.

Answer (score 2):

Written clearly and correctly and think he's just trying to say:

"No one has made book-length surveys of the continent because it would be an enormous task."

The sentence as given is much more awkward, and uses the work "enormity" incorrectly, so it's no surprise you find it difficult.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer because it's a good response to the question, but you might like to edit it to refer to the use of "enormity" as **contentious** rather than incorrect. Yes it's _often_ used to suggest wrongness or criminality, but see http://www.arrantpedantry.com/2012/11/20/the-enormity-of-a-usage-problem/ for an alternative viewpoint.